# Why does Django REST Framework provide different Authentication mechanisms

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, restful-authentication

Why does Django REST Framework implement a different Authentication mechanism than the built-in Django mechanism?

To wit, there are two settings classes that one can configure:

1. `settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` which handles the Django-level authentication, and
2. `settings.REST_FRAMEWORK['DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES']` which authenticates at the REST-Framework level

The problem I'm experiencing is that I have a Middleware layer which checks whether a user is logged-in or not.

When using a web client which authenticates via sessions, this works fine. However, from mobile or when running the test suite (i.e. authenticating using HTTP headers and tokens), the middleware detects the user as an `AnonymousUser`, but by the time we get to the REST Framework layer, the HTTP `Authorization` header is read, and the user is logged-in.

Why do these not both happen BEFORE the middleware? Furthermore, why doesn't REST Framework's authentication methods not rely on the Django authentication backend?

Comment: Great question @BillyBBone. I'm experiencing the same issue. Did you ever figure out a way to authenticate DRF request in your middleware?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Django Rest Framework does not perform authentication in middleware by default for the same reason that Django does not perform authentication in middleware by default: middleware applies to ALL views, and is overkill when you only want to authenticate access to a small portion of your views. Also, having the ability to provide different authentication methods for different API endpoints is a very handy feature.

Rest Framework's authentication methods do not rely on the Django authentication backend because the Django's backend is optimised for the common case, and is intimitely linked to the user model. Rest Framework aims to make it easy to:

1. Use many different authentication methods. (You want HMAC based authentication? done! This is not possible with django auth framework)
2. Serve API data without ever needing a database behind it. (You have a redis database with all your data in-memory? Serve it in milliseconds without ever waiting for a round trip to DB user model.)

Comment: do you know of a way to create a middleware for DRF requests?

Comment: @SteveWalsh The same way as middleware for any request. If you need it to run specifically on DRF views, you can test whether the current view subclasses from DRF's base ApiView.

Comment: How could you test whether the current view subclasses from DRF's base ApiView?

Comment: @awidgery `ApiView in __self__.__class__.__mro__` I think.

Comment: Thanks! That works in `process_view` because at that stage I have `view_func` so I can do `cls = view_func.func_dict['cls']` and then `APIView in cls.__mro__` - is there a way to test this in the `process_request` middleware, though?

Comment: Does anybody have an actual answer to this question? What's the difference between the two?

Comment: @psilocybin `process_request` middleware runs before url routing and only considers request headers. `process_view` middleware runs after url routing is complete and can consider the view to which this request will be routed. Therefore there is no way to test this in the `process_request` middleware. The best you can do is test if the requested url path starts with some prefix that you know your API endpoints live under.

Comment: @Thomas thanks for the reply. I'm looking at using token-based middleware (oauth2) which authenticates via LDAP. Do these authentication backends need to live both in Django `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` and Django REST `REST_FRAMEWORK['DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES']`, assuming that these are required for all API routes?

Comment: I assume you mean OAuth 2.0 bearer tokens? Generally you would want to have your OAuth2 user authentication happen on a proper webpage interactively, this would be managed by standard Django authentication backends. Then the client would be passed a bearer token that would be used for all subsequent API requests and would be managed by rest framework authentication system. You would need to setup both systems, but they will be used at different times for different purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Thomas' answer explains the why quite well.  My answer deals more with what you can do about it.  I also have a middleware class that determines the current user.  I need this because we have some automatic processes (cron) and I want to attribute these to a super user, and I have some model functions that don't have access to the request object but need to know who the current user is for various functions.  So this created some issues as you noticed when we added an API via the REST framework.  Here's my solution (yours will need to be adjusted to your use case):

```
from threading import local

_user = local()     # thread-safe storage for current user used by middleware below

class CurrentUserMiddleware(object):
    """ Defines Middleware for storing the currently active user """

    def process_request(self, request):
        if not request:
            # Clear the current user if also clearing the request.
            _user.value = 1  # One represents automatic actions done by super admin

        else:
            _user.value = request.user

            if not _user.value or not _user.value.is_authenticated:
                try:
                    authenticator = TokenAuthentication()
                    auth = authenticator.authenticate(request)

                    if auth:
                        _user.value = auth[0]
                except Exception as e:
                    pass

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        _user.value = None

        return response
```

The authenticator bit deals with seeing if the request has been authenticated by the REST Framework and getting the user.